# Find a definite integral and calculate the average temperature

Tags: calculus, integration

A geographer measures the temperature in a place with a mild climate. He sees that the temperature is very well approximated by the function $y=0.25T_0+T_0sin^2\left(x\pi \right)$. He has taken measurements for two full years,
$0 ≤ x ≤ 2.$

Make a qualitative sketch of the temperature function and use a suitable definite integral to calculate the average temperature over the whole measurement period.

Like I need someone to guide me through this, I think I need to integrate y, but idk how? Do I take T as x? but there is already x in the equation. Do I replace T with 2 since hat is the duration of the measurement? What do I do with T??

Comment: Ask yourself: $1)$ What is $y$ a function of? $2)$ What is $T_0$ here?

Comment: The function is about the temp measurements that were taken. And T is probably time? or Temperature.

Comment: Confusing notation , but the idea is that y corresponds to temperature and x corresponds to time. I figured this out using the description of the data analysed

Comment: @Buraian, yes. But the OP should know the meaning of $T_0$ and should know, mathematically, what $y$ is a function of.

Comment: how do you know that x corresponds to time? I understand the T is temperature now

Comment: x is the dependent variable, they told he made plot of temperature with time

Comment: Also says for two full years, $0 \leq x \leq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

It is given that $y = 0.25T_0 + T_0\sin^2(x\pi)$. Note that $T_0$ is just a fixed constant. This is a function of $x$, so we find it natural to write $y$ using function notation as $y = T(x)$. You should ask yourself what the variable $x$ represents in this question based on the problem data. To calculate the average temperature, there is a useful formula that says if $f$ is a function on the interval $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then the average value of $f$ over $[a,b]$ (call it Avg) is  $$\text{Avg} = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx$$
See if you can apply this result to your problem.